# Failed to post notification on channel null in Android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Iam developing an android application where I am trying to show notifications when a particular time is set.

I can see that there is an error coming which says that

> "Failed to post notification on channel null"

I have attached the code for reference.
This is WorkReminder.java

### WorkReminder.java

```
    public class WorkReminder extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private int notificationId = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_reminder);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create reminders");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        findViewById(R.id.set_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText reminder = findViewById(R.id.reminder_text);
        TimePicker timePicker = findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        // Set notificationId & text.
        Intent intent = new Intent(WorkReminder.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
        intent.putExtra("todo", reminder.getText().toString());

        // getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, flags)
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(WorkReminder.this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.set_button:
                int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
                int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

                // Create time.
                Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                long alarmStartTime = startTime.getTimeInMillis();

                // Set alarm.
                // set(type, milliseconds, intent)
                alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime, alarmIntent);

                Toast.makeText(this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.cancel_button:
                alarm.cancel(alarmIntent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the AlarmReceiver.java

### AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get id & message from intent.
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("todo");

        // When notification is tapped, call MainActivity.
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mainIntent, 0);

        NotificationManager myNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Prepare notification.
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder!")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        // Notify
        myNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
}
```

This is the activity_work_reminder.xml

## activity_work_reminder.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WorkReminder">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/reminder_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
            android:text="Staying hygiene is more important during COVID - 19. Ensure your safety by creating simple reminders to keep you noted."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reminder_text"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_edges"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Reminder"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.18"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reminder_header" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reminder_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/set_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:text="set reminder"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_edges"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cancel_button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.603"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timePicker" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_edges"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timePicker" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Suggest me a method to show notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the notification channel before posting the notification. Please, discover the documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java

> Before you can deliver the notification on Android 8.0 and higher, you must register your app's notification channel with the system by passing an instance of NotificationChannel to createNotificationChannel(). So the following code is blocked by a condition on the SDK_INT version:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}}
```

Comment: I had tried your suggestion but its failing to work. Kindly send me any other option.

Comment: Please, provide me more information. What's going wrong? I suppose after you had added notification channel this error disappeared but instead appeared something new